# UIWebView displaying blank screen when loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ios8

My app has to be able to download a file and display it. The format could be any of the major format types. I have been doing this with a UIWebView but when iOS 8 rolled out it broke this feature. I am wondering if this an issue with iOS 8 or is there a work around that I can use?

Here is my code:

```
//To show how I create the file path
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
//Name is the file's name that I get from the web service I use.
NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];


- (void) showFile:(NSString *)path andFileName:(NSString *)name
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

            NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.filePath];

            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
            [self.webView loadRequest:request];

            self.webView.delegate = self;

            [self.view addSubview:self.webView];

     });
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was in my case and so I wanted to post the answer.

I was using a direct file path:

```
    NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
```

When I should have been using a relative path like so:

```
NSString *resourceDocPath;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
resourceDocPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

They changes the file structure for iOS 8 which is why my code wasn't working since I was looking in the wrong place. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem rendering a pdf document on iOS 8.

So far, I've noticed this only for pdfs. So i check and see if the file is a pdf or not.

This is what i'm doing as a workaround.

```
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileLocation];
[self.webView loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: That is what I am seeing but for me it is all file types that it won't display. I have even tested the answer you have given and it just tells me %PDF not found. Which would seem like it is a corruption issue but it is only on iOS 8+. If I run it on anything before iOS 8 it works as expected. So I don't think it would be a corruption issue. Unless it is a corruption issue and AFNetworking, which I am using to download the files, has issues with iOS 8. I will look into that.